# How to fix difference in behavior of activesupport 3.0.0 compare to 2.x?

Tags: ruby, activesupport

I am using Hash#to_xml in my Sinatra application. It did work till I moved to actviesupport 3.0.0

Is there a difference in usage of activesupport in 3.0.0?

For example this works fine

```
gem 'activesupport', '2.3.5'
require 'active_support'
{}.to_xml
```

and

```
gem 'activesupport', '3.0.0'
require 'active_support'
{}.to_xml
```

generates: NoMethodError: undefined method `to_xml' for {}:Hash

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ActiveSupport no longer loads all its components when you `require` it. This allows you to cherry-pick the functionality that you want.

```
require "active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions"
{}.to_xml
```

Or if you really want all of ActiveSupport:

```
require "active_support/all"
```