# How can I convert JSON to XML in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, json, activesupport

Is there any way to convert JSON to XML in Ruby?

Comment: I added the `activesupport` tag and turned your title into a question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
require 'active_support' #for to_xml() 'gem install activesupport' use the 2.3 branch
require 'json' #part of ruby 1.9 but otherwise 'gem install json'

my_json = "{\"test\":\"b\"}"
my_xml = JSON.parse(my_json).to_xml(:root => :my_root)
```

Also note the root argument of to_xml. If you don't specify a root it'll use the word 'hash' as the root which isn't very nice to look at.

Comment: Do I need some gem for the `active_support`? I'm getting an error when I try to `require` it.

Comment: yes. Active Support is part of Ruby on Rails. You should be able to install it with 'gem install activesupport'

Comment: Now whenever I try to run it, I get the following error: `undefined method `to_xml' for #<Array:0x1013b2b60> (NoMethodError)`. `JSON.parse` should be returning a Hash, should it not?

Comment: Yes, it should be returning a hash. Can you post your xml?

Comment: I don't have XML, I have some JSON, it is the JSON source returned by the SimpleNote API. It is one heck of a lot of data. Here is the JSON I'm getting back: https://gist.github.com/b41cd5bb01f6d5de1053

Comment: It works fine for me. I'm using json_pure (1.2.0) and active_support (2.3.5). What versions are you using?

Comment: I'm using json_pure (1.4.6) and active_support (3.0.3). Should I uninstall them and try with the versions you're using?

Comment: I can't see it hurting anything.

Comment: Yeah it looks like they changed activesupport a ton for 3.0 and the to_xml methods are no longer there.

Comment: After downgrading json_pure and active_support I'm getting this error:https://gist.github.com/00e934871ea4529fd132

Comment: And, also, I'll be in the Ruby chat if you would like to continue there.

Comment: What version of rubygems are you running?

Comment: Ok. I'm also in the ruby channel now.

Comment: Activesupport no longer imports all functionality when you require it. You have to either explicitly say to import everything or specify what you want. If you got the to_xml function was not defined then you might have this problem.



See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642905/how-to-fix-difference-in-behavior-of-activesupport-3-0-0-compare-to-2-x

Answer (score 8):

Regarding @rwilliams aka r-dub answer:

[ActiveSupport moved its components](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) into separate modules for granularity. Rather than load everything all at once, we can tell it to load only certain subsets, or, if we still choose, we can load everything at once. No matter what, we can not use `require 'activesupport'` like we used to, instead we have to use `require 'activesupport/all'` or one of the subsets.

```
>> require 'active_support/core_ext/array/conversions' #=> true
>> [{:a => 1, :b => 2}, {:c => 3}].to_xml
=> "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<objects type="array">\n  <objects a="1" b="2" type="hash"/>\n  <objects c="3" type="hash"/>\n</objects>\n"
```

In addition, ActiveSupport contains JSON support, so you can do the entire conversion with AR:

```
>> require 'active_support/all' #=> true
>> json = {'foo'=>'bar'}.to_json #=> "{"foo":"bar"}"
>> ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json).to_xml #=> "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<hash>\n  <foo>bar</foo>\n</hash>\n"
```

The first line loads in the XML and JSON conversions. The second line sets up a JSON sample to use for testing. The third line takes the pretend JSON, decodes it, then converts it to XML.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers do not allow for simple recursive conversions. As explained in [this answer on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/51570/63013), you'll need a custom helper to create the simple format you're looking for.

It will turn this...

```
data = [
  { 'name' => 'category1',
    'subCategory' => [
      { 'name' => 'subCategory1',
        'product' => [
          { 'name' => 'productName1',
            'desc' => 'desc1' },
          { 'name' => 'productName2',
            'desc' => 'desc2' } ]
      } ]
  },
  { 'name' => 'category2',
    'subCategory' => [
      { 'name' => 'subCategory2.1',
        'product' => [
          { 'name' => 'productName2.1.1',
            'desc' => 'desc1' },
          { 'name' => 'productName2.1.2',
            'desc' => 'desc2' } ]
      } ]
  },
]
```

...into this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <category>
    <name>category1</name>
    <subCategory>
      <name>subCategory1</name>
      <product>
        <name>productName1</name>
        <desc>desc1</desc>
      </product>
      <product>
        <name>productName2</name>
        <desc>desc2</desc>
      </product>
    </subCategory>
  </category>
  <category>
    <name>category2</name>
    <subCategory>
      <name>subCategory2.1</name>
      <product>
        <name>productName2.1.1</name>
        <desc>desc1</desc>
      </product>
      <product>
        <name>productName2.1.2</name>
        <desc>desc2</desc>
      </product>
    </subCategory>
  </category>
</root>
```

Answer (score -1):

i don't know a magic gem to do it, but what you can do easily is xml to hash and hash to json.

```
require 'active_support'
my_hash = Hash.from_xml(my_xml)
```

then

```
require 'json'
my_json = my_hash.to_json
```

Comment: I am trying to convert JSON to XML, not XML to JSON

Comment: Are those weird quotes going to work, anyway? This does not look too healthy.

Comment: @elusive: Yeah, they look funky to me too. I think they're smart quotes.