# Ruby GeoJSON to KML

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, kml, geojson

I have a Sinatra app that i'm `post`ing GeoJSON (polygon) to.. I'm looking for a gem/ script to convert the JSON into a KML, before I att. to an e-mail (using [mail](http://rubygems.org/gems/mail) gem).

The closest thing I could find was [georuby](https://github.com/nofxx/georuby), which doesn't seem to have such a conversion yet, surely there is a way...?? Or perhaps this is better achieved manually :?

New to Ruby *(from a Python/ JavaScript background)*, so baby steps are appreciated!

**Edit:** for my purposes, it was easier to just ("manually") transform the coords, and interpolate a template kml erb/ string.

Comment: Since KML is XML, if everything in the JSON conforms to the KML schema (key names etc) you could [try converting the JSON to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4273308/335847) and perhaps it will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

(I couldn't find a pure-Ruby library that converts KML to GeoJSON, either...?)

If the `ogr2ogr` binary is available on your system and you can write to the tmp directory:

```
require 'tmpdir'
require 'fileutils'

tmpdir = Dir.mktmpdir
geojson_path = File.join(tmpdir, 'a.geojson') # the input
kml_path = File.join(tmpdir, 'a.kml') # the output

File.open(geojson_path, 'w') do |f|
  # params[:geojson] is from the web request
  f.write params[:geojson]
end

Kernel.system 'ogr2ogr', '-f', 'KML', kml_path, geojson_path

# now you can email kml
kml = File.read(kml_path)

FileUtils.rm_rf tmpdir
```

Comment: +1 came across `ogr2ogr` too, cheers for showing me the Ruby way to call it. Think I can get Heroku to build ogr, assume it isn't in the $PATH by default.. still, weird there isn't a gem!

Comment: to get ogr2ogr on heroku, you'd need a buildpack... if you had access to a postgis server, maybe you could use a combination of [ST_GeomFromGeoJSON](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) and [ST_AsKML](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsKML.html)? you can get one from http://www.acugis.com/ for $9/mo

Answer (score 0):

You can use a new gem called [FFI-OGR](https://github.com/scooterw/ffi-ogr) to do this.

FFI, or [Foreign Function Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface), lets Ruby call functions written in other languages, without writing native code. FFI-OGR wraps the C implementation of OGR in Ruby.

Add `gem 'ffi-ogr', git: 'https://github.com/scooterw/ffi-ogr'` to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`. Then, in whatever script you're doing the conversion, you'd write something like:

```
require 'ffi-ogr'

# read in GeoJSON
geojson = OGR.read 'path/to/file.geojson'

# output as KML, write to file
geojson.to_kml 'destination/of/file.kml'
```

GeoRuby is fairly new, and the tooling isn't built out very well yet. However, [@scooterw](https://github.com/scooterw) is leading the development of some Ruby tools that do basic functionality.

Take a look at the [examples from FOSS4G 2014](https://github.com/scooterw/foss4g-examples) for more, and join [the GeoRubyists group on Github](https://github.com/geo-rubyists).